# Dropdown selected option in email

Tags: javascript, html-select, wpforms

I'm trying to get the value selected by the user in my dropdown form to be send with my email.

The values are generated with this code :

```php
function wpb_hook_javascript() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    var selectList = document.createElement("select");
    selectList.id = "mySelect";
    myDiv.appendChild(selectList);
    var activite = document.querySelectorAll(".info-box-content h3");
    console.log (activite);
    for (var i = 0; i < activite.length; i++) {
        var array = activite[i].innerText;
        console.log (array);
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = array;
        option.text = array;
        selectList.appendChild(option);
    }
    console.log ("retour var array : " + array);


</script>
<?php
}
add_action('wpforms_wp_footer', 'wpb_hook_javascript');
```

With it I get the different values on my page in the class info-box-content as h3 and make them options values for my dropdown inserted in the myDiv DIV in my form.

With the code below I want to add the HTML block with the myDiv DIV in my notification email :

```php
function wpf_dev_email_display_other_fields( $fields ) {
    return array( 'divider', 'pagebreak', 'html' );
}
     
add_filter( 'wpforms_email_display_other_fields', 'wpf_dev_email_display_other_fields', 10, 1 );
```

Everything works fine except that the value selected by the user is not in the email content.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for misusing the answer space because I don't have much reputation.
So my baby..wpb_hook_javascript() is not returning any value it's just executing the JS script. So Either you have to return something in wpb_hook_javascript() func or store the values in the PHP variable.
Also, your question is not clear, what are these:-
wpforms_email_display_other_fields,wpf_dev_email_display_other_fields,add_filter and add_action

Comment: First thank you so much for your answer.
wpforms_email_display_other_fields,wpf_dev_email_display_other_fields,add_filter and add_action are filters given by wpforms (a form plugin for wordpress) that enable the send of a custom html block added in the form in the notification email. That part works fine except that the values selected in my option list is not kept (so this part of the form - the custom html block- is in the mail but empty).
You are right the problem is that my function doesn't store any data because of my function. How can a store the value selected by the user ?